# How can I combine Python parameterized MySQL statements with a dynamic SELECT statement?

Tags: python, mysql

I have a backend database that I would to use dynamic SELECT statements for the column names.  The problem is when I use method A, the column name is correctly printed but the Mac_Address field has no surrounding ' '.  In method B, the opposite is true where the Mac_Address has it's quotes ' ' but the ' ' also appears around my column names.  How can I get both to work at the same time?

Method A)

```
mac_address = 'xx xx xx xx xx xx'
et_labels = ['RSSI','ADC0','ADC1]
sql = "SELECT %s FROM mac_tbl WHERE Mac_Address = %s" % ((','.join(map(str,et_labels))),mac_address)
cursor.execute(sql)
```

This runs:

```
SELECT RSSI, ADC0, ADC1 WHERE Mac_Address = xx xx xx xx xx xx
```

This fails because MySQL wants to see `Mac_Address` like this:  `'xx xx xx xx xx xx'`

Method B)

```
mac_address = 'xx xx xx xx xx xx'
et_labels = ['RSSI','ADC0','ADC1]
cursor.execute("""SELECT %s from mac_tbl WHERE Mac_Address = %s;""",(",".join(et_labels),mac_address))
```

This runs:

```
SELECT 'RSSI,ADC0,ADC1' WHERE Mac_Address = 'xx xx xx xx xx xx'
```

This fails because the column names have `' '` around them and aren't treated as separate names, but the `Mac_Address` field is correct.

The reason I am trying to do this is the column names are read dynamically from remote devices and they all have different configurations so I need make a list of the specific config for each device before generating my SELECT statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
mac_address = 'xx xx xx xx xx xx'
et_labels = ['RSSI','ADC0','ADC1]
query = """
   SELECT {0} FROM mac_tbl 
      WHERE Mac_Address = %s;
""".format(",".join(et_labels))
cursor.execute(query,(mac_address,))
```

In this code we are using a string formatting before execute the query (and pass the parameter)

HTH.